# WhereIN query returns null in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to find the number of user with WhereIN query, I tested with three types 1st two return user correctly but when I use the variable instead of direct data then it returns null

```
$userss = User::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->first();

        $membership = Ppv::whereIN('membership_id',[3])->count();
       dd( $membership);//its returns user correctly



 $membership = Ppv::where('membership_id',$userss->membership_id)->count();
           dd( $membership); // also return users correctly
```

but when i use it in whereIN query it returns null

```
$userss = User::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
    $membership = Ppv::whereIN('membership_id',array($userss->membership_id))->count();
   dd( $membership); // retruns null or 0
```

Comment: Did you mean `whereIn()` and not `whereIN()`?

Comment: I don't understand why you would use `whereIn` for an array with one item.

Comment: @rkg i am consudering both same. both are not working as well

Comment: @Dan because membership_ids are stored in  3,5,7

Comment: @Dan in membership_id comlum values are stored in array format with implode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using $userss, like it is an id. It is not. It is a User model. If you want to use it how you described, you need:

```
    $membership = Ppv::whereIn('membership_id',[ $userss->membership_id ])->count();
```

But if you are going to take first(), from User, you should just do:

```
    $membership = Ppv::where('membership_id',$userss->membership_id)->count();
```

Comment: not worked i also tried i am also confused. but when i insert data directly it works

Comment: Please edit your question with your solution please, to help other users.

Comment: your last update also not fits because i need in arrray,, but thanks alot , i will always remeber it

Comment: It is an array: whereIn('membership_id',[ $userss->membership_id ])

Comment: Post your solution

Answer (score 0):

$user = User::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->first();

Please check the value of  $user->membership_id;

return  Ppv::whereIN('membership_id',[$user->membership_id])->count();